# Middle centered text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Explanation

I'm trying to recreate this "middle centered text" as, for example, "Responsive Front-end Development" in [this site](http://ianlunn.co.uk). As I'm new to web dev, I looked for some templates, so I could have a start. I found two "methods" to do it, but I don't know how to measure which is better, or even if there's any better/faster (performance) way.

ps: I'm using Bootstrap in my project, so I need to `<link>` it's CSS anyway.

### Code

**Bootstrap's Jumbotron method**

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    margin-top: 190px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap's jumbotron method</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>My Centered Text</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS method**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.site-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS method</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="site-wrapper">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1>My Centered Text</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: why you didn't use CSS : `text-align:center;` ?

Comment: I used Bootstrap's text-center class. I think it does the same thing.

Comment: What is the question? Is something not working as expected?

Comment: yes it do , after re-read the question how we can help ? the two methods do same thing and which one to use depending on you to choose

Comment: I'd like to know which method is better (performance), or if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way to do it by using flexbox. It is the currently accepted standard to achieve vertical centering. A table based approach is not flexible enough.  You could do

```
.site-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; //horizontal center
  justify-content: center; //vertical center
}
```

You also do not need the `.site-wrapper-inner` class. Have a look at this: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/thunderemperor/pen/qRdrMp)

Also the reason this is better than `.jumbotron` is because bootstrap jumbotron is intended for a specific purpose. Specifically the big welcome text on a webpage. It is not a good idea to use `jumbotron` wherever you need vertical centring.

Have a look at this article about [Flexbox Vertical Centering](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't make it work. It doesn't center as expected. By the way, it wasn't me who rated down your answer.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I have also updated my answer. This should work. Make sure you remove the table styling before you apply this. I also did not down vote your question :).

Comment: I still can't get there. You can see it [here in CodePen](http://codepen.io/luizmachado/pen/qRdrrj).

Comment: Ah. Its because the parent element has limited height. Just add `height: 100%` to site-wrapper. You don't need the `site-wrapper-inner` class.

Comment: Thank you!! Sorry to keep on this, how would this method be better/faster in performance than the bootstrap's one? I updated my question with your solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132532/discussion-between-yathi-and-luiz).